# How can i get the first nearest date in the past?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have this arrays

```
const datesToBeChecked = ['2020-07-03','2020-07-06', '2020-07-13', '2020-07-20']
const dateToCheckFor = '2020-07-12';
```

I need to get the first nearest date in the past - so when the date is `2020-07-12` i need to get
`2020-07-06` from datesToBeChecked.

*WHAT I TRIED*

I tried this code

```
datesToBeChecked.forEach(date => {
      let diff = moment(dateToCheckFor).diff(moment(date), 'days');
      console.log(diff);
      if (diff > 0) {
        if (nearestDate) {
          if (moment(date).diff(moment(nearestDate), 'days') < 0) {
            nearestDate = date;
          }
        } else {
          nearestDate = date;
        }
      }
    });
```

but that gives me the earliest date in the array - 2020-07-03. But i need the first `BEFORE THE DATE I CHECK FOR`

Comment: just do `.add(-1, "days")`

Comment: I don't understant. Where i need to use `add`? Can you please provide an answer so i can also accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your logic is almost there. You don't need the nested `if` conditional. In essense, what you want is to cache the difference, and compare the current difference with the cached difference. If the cached difference is smaller, then we know the current date is the nearest one. Otherwise, we continue for the search.

This solution will work even if the dates are not sorted in chronological order (oldest to newest):

```js
const datesToBeChecked = ['2020-07-03', '2020-07-06', '2020-07-13', '2020-07-20']
const dateToCheckFor = '2020-07-12';

let nearestDate;
let cachedDiff = Infinity;
datesToBeChecked.forEach(date => {
  let diff = moment(dateToCheckFor).diff(moment(date), 'days');
  if (diff > 0 && diff < cachedDiff) {
    cachedDiff = diff;
    nearestDate = date;
  }
});

console.log(nearestDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the anser

Answer (score 1):

The first element is the closest date in the **past** (at least yesterday, today results won't show up).

If empty then `dateToCheckFor` elements does not contain any date in past.

```
const mappedDates = dateToCheckFor
    .map(d => moment(dateToCheckFor).diff(moment(d), 'days'))
    .filter(diff => diff <= -1)
    .sort()
    .reverse();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try sorting all of the dates in a hash table first. So you would have a hash table:

```
{
  date1: difference,
  date2: difference,
  ...
}
```

then you would sort the objects values, such as here: [Sorting object property by values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-object-property-by-values)

then take the first date from that, which is before the `dateToCheckFor`

I hope this is not too inefficient for you.

Comment: @Petar maybe you can filter before and then sort the elements

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way with good ole vanilla js. Moment.js weighs 230+kb

```js
const datesToBeChecked = ['2020-07-03', '2020-07-06', '2020-07-13', '2020-07-20']
const dateToCheckFor = '2020-07-12';
dateToCheckFor_d = new Date(dateToCheckFor).getTime();
let possibilities = datesToBeChecked.filter(dt => {
  return (new Date(dt).getTime() < dateToCheckFor_d)

})
possibilities.sort().reverse()
console.log(possibilities[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code just update the below line

```
if (moment(date).diff(moment(nearestDate), 'days') < 0
```

to

```
if (moment(date).diff(moment(nearestDate), 'days') > 0
```